# Get value of LookUp field through query

Tags: soql, sobject

I am having a problem with a query. I am trying to extract the name of `Assigned_To__c` field (which is a look up field of `Employee Rosters` object).

The query I have used for this is

```
SELECT id, name, Assigned_To__r.Name 
FROM Work_Request__c 
WHERE Assigned_To__r.id =: id limit 201
```

The query is returning the value for the `id` and `name` fields correctly but for `Assigned_To__r.Name`, the `id` itself is getting returned not the `employee name`. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of Two issues here:

1. You are using the debug log to look at the value of the Query results i.e.

   ```
   Contact c = [Select Account.Name From Contact]
   system.debug(c);
   ```

To debug the actual name you will need to

```
system.debug(c.Account.Name);
```

2. The name field is a text field and was not populated on inserting the record, in this case the name field will default to the ID of the record.

Comment: As you correctly guessed i am trying to check the value via debug log. ill try ur method and also will check if the field is populated, which i think it is.

Comment: And it worked like a charm. It was the problem with the debug. i am able to see the employee names now... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you did not enter Name field for a record (ie) in this case it is **Employee Rosters** record/sObject, the Name field by default will have the ID of the record as the value!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use Assigned_To__c directly - and maybe it's a typo, but I think you need a colon - not a semicolon:

SELECT id, name, Assigned_To__r.Name FROM Work_Request__c WHERE
Assigned_To__c =:id limit 201

Comment: Assigned_To__c will return the id , since it's a lookup. Yes, the semicolon does appear to be a typo, else the query is fine.

Comment: The OP is specifically requesting that he/she be able to access the Name property of the record.

Answer (score -1):

Try.... SELECT id, name, Assigned_To__c.Name FROM Work_Request__c WHERE Assigned_To__c.id =;id limit 201

Comment: You cannot reference relationships via __c. In addition, your answer continues the OPs typo of the `;` in the query